# Replace part of a string in a Struts2 tag

Tags: tags, struts2, replace, inline

Is it possible to replace the value of a property in Struts2?
I want to resolve a mimetype image, and it would be really useful to do something like:

```
<img src="<s:property value='%{mimetype.replace("/", ".")}'/>" ...
```

Can I do something on the fly like this?

Thanks!

Comment: `<img src="<s:property value='mimetype.replace("/", ".")' />" alt="...">`

Comment: @Ischin Why isn't this an answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
<img src="<s:property value='%{mimetype.replace("/", ".")}'/>
```

Yes it's possible ognl allows to use string mehthods directly